# How to incorporate my podcast rss feed on my personal website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a podcast host (anchor.fm) that submits my shows RSS feed to all streaming services like iTunes, etc.

I would like to have that RSS feed on my website which updates as I upload new shows to anchor.

To give an example of what I'm referring to https://transistor.fm/features/embeddable-podcast-player or http://podcasts.joerogan.net/

Any tips on how to achieve this?
Is this possible with HTML/CSS and Javascript? If not, what would be the proper language to use?

Comment: I searched on here, I should have googled further. My apology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use embed websites to take the data from the RSS feed and give you a JS object in return. eg http://feed2js.org/

Alternatively, RSS feeds are just XML data so you can make an ajax request to the RSS feed URL and parse the XML response. This will give you all the data you need.

Here is an example of what an item might look like in XML

```
        <item>
            <title>
                <![CDATA[Lorem ipsum 2019-11-19T15:06:00Z]]>
            </title>
            <description>
                <![CDATA[Voluptate aliquip pariatur labore id ad.]]>
            </description>
            <link>http://example.com/test/1574175960</link>
            <guid isPermaLink="true">http://example.com/test/1574175960</guid>
            <dc:creator>
                <![CDATA[John Smith]]>
            </dc:creator>
            <pubDate>Tue, 19 Nov 2019 15:06:00 GMT</pubDate>
        </item>
```

See [Parsing XML RSS feed using jQuery and Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212922/parsing-xml-rss-feed-using-jquery-and-ajax) for more

Comment: "so you can make an ajax request to the RSS feed URL" — Unlikely. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy